# Using number bases to prove combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, solution-verification

[image]

Rewriting the grid in base 8,

[image]

I claim that at this point, it is essentially proven. If I choose any set of numbers as described in the question, the numbers I select must contain exactly one every last digit(0-7), and exactly one of every second digit 0-7. Note that last digit of 0 would imply that it is no longer in the same residue since the numbers start from 1, so the number chosen that last digit of 0 bears an extra value of 8 rather than 0.
This means the sum of the numbers chosen are,
$$S=(70+60+50+40+30+20+10+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+10)_8$$
$$S=(8(7+6+5+4+3+2+1) + 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)_{10}$$
$$S=260_{10} \ \blacksquare$$

(Please confirm the validity of my proof, it's very different from the given answer to the question)

Comment: @RobertZ Not asking for the answer, it is already provided with the question, I'm asking if my method is correct.

Comment: Yes, your argument is fine.

Comment: @Mdren Your argument is correct. The same question is discussed at 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787856/sum-of-numbers-on-chessboard

and 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876806/show-that-sum-obtained-in-this-chessboard-is-already-260?

Comment: @Mdren BTW what is the "very different" given answer to the question?

Comment: Very nice way to think about it. You could avoid the special case of the numbers in the last column by renumbering the square from $0$ to $63$ and observing that this simply reduced the sum of the chosen set by $8$. Now $S=8(1+\ldots+7)+(1+\ldots+7)=9\cdot28=252$, and adding the missing $8$ gives the desired result.

Comment: @RobertZ http://prntscr.com/roazmo After looking at the answers in the link, I don't think it is very different, mine and theirs both boil down to the same idea, but I just thought my use of number bases was too ambitious for me to trust

Answer (score 1):

Each numbercan be represented as $8r+c$ where $c$ is the column number and $r$ is the row number.(starting from 0) One number must be selected from every row, this means that every distinct $r$ and distinct $c$ must be selected.

$$\frac{8 \cdot 9}{2} + \frac {8 \cdot(7\cdot 8)}{2}=36+224=260$$

So your proof is valid.